# selecting values where the value is between two strings in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to run a query that selects an id that's between two strings. the query I'm using is

```
select netid from ALL_GROUP_MEMBERS_VIEW where netid >'aa%' and netid < 'b%' and
      gid='213' order by netid
```

This obviously isn't working, but I'm not sure how to get those values. Netid is a unique identifier for an individual.

Comment: Could you post some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: Put sample data in text, and the result you wish to achieve so that the others may better help you.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I meant to post "Can't post data because the table contains sensitive information". Mureinik's answer below fixed my issue. Once I took the wildcard out, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%` character is a wildcard for the `LIKE` operator, and has no function (other than as a literal) in string comparison operations.
If you remove it, you should get the right behavior:

```
SELECT   netid
FROM     all_group_members_view
WHERE    netid > 'aa' AND netid < 'b' AND gid = '213'
ORDER BY netid
```

To make this query more elegant, you can replace the pair of `>` and `<` operators with a single `between` operator:

```
SELECT   netid
FROM     all_group_members_view
WHERE    netid BETWEEN 'aa' AND 'b' AND gid = '213'
ORDER BY netid
```

Comment: Thanks. Taking the wildcard out fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select netid 
    from ALL_GROUP_MEMBERS_VIEW 
    where substr(netid,1,1) between 'A' and 'B' 
        and gid='213' 
    order by netid
```